# After joining the slave node and adding cni slave node is not getting ready but master node is getting ready

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

```
 Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:43:45 +0530   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:40:45 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:43:45 +0530   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:40:45 +0530   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:43:45 +0530   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:40:45 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:43:45 +0530   Wed, 26 Dec 2018 10:40:45 +0530   KubeletNotReady              runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

i am getting the above error.Is the problem with the slave node or the master node.what should i do to make the all the joined nodes ready

Comment: Which CNI you are using?

Comment: @jaya rohith, Have you checked healthiness of the core cluster Pods: `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`?

Comment: i am using waveworks

Comment: https://www.weave.works/blog/weave-net-kubernetes-integration/ check this link for the cni i am using

Comment: after checking health the output is

coredns is not ready only master pods are in ready status

Comment: @jaya rohith, Have you checked logs for CoreDNS Pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because /etc/cni/net.d is not containing the files present in the master node copy them manually from master to worker and it works